# MCA package has no plot_coordinates attribute

Tags: python

I tried to display the plot of MCA using the prince library, but the plot couldn't show. This is my code that I've made so far.

```
mca = prince.MCA(n_components = 2)
mca = mca.fit(df[mca_cols])
ax = mca.plot_coordinates(df[mca_cols])
```

I tried to run the code, but it doesn't work. Can someone help me? Thank you in advance